# How to force Facebook to rescrape link preview on each share

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-php-sdk, scrape

I found a website today (*www.mytwin.fun*) 
**Whenever i comment this url anywhere on Facebook, it shows random image as preview**. How do they do it?

I tried using Facebook graph api and Curl but it doesn't work without opening the site on a web browser.

**Can anyone guide me to find a solution for this**?

Comment: There are ways to "Bump" a stackoverflow question, to draw attention to it when you feel it's not attracting enough attention.  The most effective way is to find someone with reputation to place a bounty on it.  Or you can place your own bounty on it.  Other methods defined here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82271/how-to-move-up-bump-questions-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Also, the reason your question hasn't received any attention is because it is very poorly formed.  There is no code sample, and you didn't tell us what you tried.  So it doesn't seem to be about programming which makes it off topic.  Asking for a guide about a subjective concept isn't in the spirit of stackoverflow questions and answers.  Your question needs to be more specific, include a code sample, telling us what you tried, and bonus point for fixing spelling errors and grammar errors.